# Scrapy Crawler excel output

Tags: python, excel, scrapy, web-crawler, scraper

I am new to python and scrapy, however I was trying to develop a crawler and scraper to extract list of products on an amazon page,

the scraped info must have name, price and prime availability. Items are scraped however every item scraped is when outputted in a csv file is entirely in one single cell.

[image]

All I want is to make each product and its corresponding details be outputted in each cell distinctly.

The logic is:

```
items= []   
    for products in response.xpath('//*[@id="mainResults"]/ul'):
       item = amazonlist()

       item['Title'] = products.css('a>h2::text').extract()
       item['Price'] = products.css(' div > div > div > a > span.a-size-base.a-color-price.s-price.a-text-bold::text').extract()
       item['Prime'] = products.css(' div > div > div > i::attr(aria-label)').extract()

       items.append(item)
    return items
```

Can you guide me with this ?

Answer (score 0):

I've been playing with some web scraping my self recently. The way I've been pulling things from a web page has been by using lxml to get the html and then I store that into a text file and then sort through it from there.

Hope I helped.

Comment: But that would still require human intervention, all I want is to directly output the contents organized in excel sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't run your example and have only part of your code, two ideas. Both may or may not cause your data being conglomerated in one cell:

1. You are returning all items at once, rather than *yielding* them one by one (look up Python *generators* if you're unsure what this means). Try this instead:

   ```
   items= []   
   for products in response.xpath('//*[@id="mainResults"]/ul'):
       item = amazonlist()

       item['Title'] = products.css('a>h2::text').extract()
       item['Price'] = products.css(' div > div > div > a > span.a-size-base.a-color-price.s-price.a-text-bold::text').extract()
       item['Prime'] = products.css(' div > div > div > i::attr(aria-label)').extract()

       yield item
   ```
2. The `extract` method returns a list of results, one for every match. If every `products` instance in the loop contains multiple products in itself, they all match. You would have to break the query further down to loop through each individual product. You can use `pdb` or a `print` statement to check if, for example, `item['Title']` contains a list of strings rather than one.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have even tried this code, I still get the very same output.

Comment: Could you post the rest of the code and/or the specific site you're trying to scrape?